# PHPUnit incompatible con xdebug

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug

Error de Xdebug al ejecutar PHPUnit:

Estoy enfrentando un problema al ejecutar PHPUnit con Xdebug habilitado en mi entorno de desarrollo. Cuando intento ejecutar PHPUnit, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
PHP Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277
...
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php:80
...
```

He realizado varias acciones para intentar solucionar el problema, incluyendo:

1. Actualización de Composer.
2. Verificación de versiones (Versión de Xdebug: 3.2.1) y (phpunit/phpunit: ^10.3).
3. Añadí las siguientes líneas a mi archivo php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
```

Sin embargo, el problema persiste. Me gustaría saber si alguien ha experimentado este problema antes y si hay alguna solución que me esté pasando por alto. No quiero desinstalar ni Xdebug ni PHPUnit, así que estoy buscando una solución que me permita utilizar ambas herramientas en conjunto.

¿Alguna idea de qué podría estar causando este error y cómo podría solucionarlo?

¡Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionarme!